# Get cloud asset details via GCP pubsub

Tags: google-cloud-platform, push-notification, google-cloud-pubsub

I have created a pubsub topic and subscriber and configured a public API for receiving the push notification. I have able to receive sample push notification in the API through topic. I would like to know if there is any way in which I can receive all GCP asset creation/ updation details as push notification via pub sub. I need all the details like asset creation date, who created, project etc...Is this doable in GCP pubsub

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 solutions to achieve that:

1. Use Cloud Asset inventory
2. Use Audit logs

---

[Cloud Asset inventory monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/monitoring-asset-changes) is a built in solution that publish a message on each asset change

The tradeoff that, for now, all [the assets aren't supported](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/supported-asset-types). The most common yes, but depends on your needs.

---

The other solution is to create a [Cloud Logging sink to PubSub](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2), with a filter only on the [System Audit Logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit#system-event)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can we get asset owner details from Cloud Asset inventory like asset creation date, who created, project details etc.

Comment: Yes, you have that data in the message (in the asset data: https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/reference/rest/v1/Asset)

Comment: Thanks for that.....I have seen this but where it is giving the creator details, associated users etc

Comment: under which key in Asset data (https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/reference/rest/v1/Asset) I can see the creator details….